# classList does not work as expected inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a slider that shows rotate slides on desktop with swipper slider,
I destroy the slider on mobile and would like to show 3 static slides that do not rotate with a show more button.

I added a class called hidden to all the elements except the first 3 and added a button to show more slides on click.

Now when you click on the button I would like to remove the hidden class from all the slides elements but it does not work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="icon-slider">

<div class="swiper-container js-icon-slider">

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="img-wrap">image here</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And my JS code:

```
 var slider = document.querySelector('.icon-slider'),
     slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide'),
     btnMore = '<div class="more-btn-wrap"><button class="wp-block-button__link">View all</button></div>';

    for (let i = 2; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }

    if (!slider.querySelector(".more-btn-wrap")) {
        slider.innerHTML = slider.innerHTML + btnMore;
    }

    let btn = document.querySelector('.more-btn-wrap');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.remove();

        slides.forEach(slide => slide.classList.remove('hidden'));
    });
```

When I just try to put this line in the console it works as expected so I think it's something with the addEventListener

```
slides.forEach(slide => slide.classList.remove('hidden'));
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? How many `.slide` elements do you have? Please add a [mcve].

Comment: why start from 3, not from 0?

Comment: Only this looks weird, otherwise nothing's wrong in your code

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Works as expected.](https://codepen.io/oiufjdhgyd/pen/oNbLRaJ)

Answer (score -3):

You don't need 2 for loops, add eventlistener inside for loop and remove second for loop inside addeventlistener also remove 3 and type 0 to start loop from 0

```
    <style type="text/css">

        .slide {
          width: 80px;
          height: 80px;
          background-color: red;
          border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .hidden {
          opacity: 0.1;
        }

    </style>

    <button class="btn">Button</button>
    <div class="slider">
       <div class="slide">Slide1</div>
       <div class="slide">Slide2</div>
       <div class="slide">Slide3</div>
    </div>

<script>

    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    let slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.slide');

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].classList.add('hidden');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

                slides[i].classList.remove('hidden');

        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: may be because add 3 listener instead of one is not a solution. One works perfectly well.

Comment: And what exactly did you fix? The problem wasn't even demonstrated.

Comment: @gre_gor i fixed that author of the question can't fix